# Getting Gradle to publish a source Jar instead of a standard compiled Jar

Tags: gradle

I am slowly moving two projects over to Gradle. Project A produces a jar file that is used by Project B.

Project A is a GWT component and Project B is a GWT application.

How do I get Gradle to generate a Jar that contains the Java source code of Project A rather than the compiled classes?

I have tried adding the following to the build.gradle file, but this generates a second Jar file containing the source - I want the main artefact to contain the source, so that it is published to my local Maven repository when I run the install task.

```
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives sourceJar
}
```

Is there a way to override the standard Jar creation task?

Comment: For anyone else just wanting default JAR removed: `configurations.archives.artifacts.removeAll { it.archiveTask.is jar }`

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own 'myArtifacts' configuration and publish that instead. Note that since the `install` task is of type [Upload](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.html), you should be able to change the default artifacts configuration from `archives` to `sourceArchives`:

```
configurations{
  sourceArchives
}

artifacts{
  sourceArchives sourceJar
}

install.configuration = configurations.sourceArchives
```

Hopefully, `install` should now just publish members of `sourceArchives` configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this - by the way, how do you know that the install task is of type Upload?

Comment: It's in the Gradle docs (see the 45.2 Tasks section): http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html